# Why wasn't my accepted answer awarded the bounty even though it's still within the grace period?

Tags: discussion, support

The particular **[question of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826771/luaplus-how-to-make-a-function-return-a-table/20013898#20013898)**.

I thought the point of a grace period was to allow the OP to review and accept last minute answers posted just prior to bounty expiration. Why would my answer not be eligible for the bounty even though it was posted 20 minutes prior to actual expiration?

Even now the question shows 3 hours left on the grace period. Has the rule for this changed or is this a bug?

Comment: What makes you think your question is not eligible for the bounty?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well the OP already accepted my answer but I was not awarded the bounty.

Comment: Then I guess you'd have to ask him why he didn't award the bounty also.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Isn't it automatic when the issuer marks an answer as accept?

Comment: No, not automatic. I'd wait until the grace period expires. If you don't get it, come back here.

Comment: No, it's automatic when the grace period expires.

Comment: ah okie thanks. I wasn't aware of that point.

Comment: But your answer does not [meet the criteria](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for automatic awarding at the moment (only has 1 upvote) and the auto award is only 50% of the bounty anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I think the OP is asking why the bounty wasn't automatically awarded even though his answer was accepted.

Comment: @MartinSmith If the asker accepts the answer during the bounty period, it gets automatically awarded the full bounty amount no matter what, when the grace period expires.

Comment: @animuson - Ah I had the wrong idea on that then. Thanks!

Comment: @animuson Just to confirm, the bounty period *does not* include the grace period correct? So in my current scenario, as it stands, the OP has to manually award the bounty even though he marked an accepted answer because it's the grace period. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. The bounty period is the phase of time that the question is being actively advertised. The grace period is some extra time the person gets to award their bounty after the fact.